# How to isolate the loader screen code in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I have created this custom code to create a loader in my project. The problem is that I have to copy and paste this function in all my classes. Is there any way I can declare this code in one global functions class and just use them wherever I want to use by calling.

```
import NVActivityIndicatorView


let activityIndicatorView = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 60, height:60), type: .ballTrianglePath, color: .black)
    let blurView = UIView()

func startLoader(){

            DispatchQueue.main.async
                {
                        self.blurView.isHidden = false

                        self.blurView.frame = self.view.frame
                        self.blurView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

                        self.view.addSubview(self.blurView)
                        self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.blurView.center
                         self.view.addSubview(self.activityIndicatorView)

                        self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
            }
        }

func stopLoader(){
        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
            self.blurView.isHidden = true

        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you mean you use these two views in every view controller of your app?

Comment: you can create UIView extension

Comment: @Sweeper yes I have to use this in every viewController and it uses the cocoapods function.So I am not sure how it works

Comment: @jawadAli will it work even if i use the cocoapods function in the extension?

Comment: yes .. no issues

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Create function to get **activityIndicatorView** and **blurView**. Because you don't need to repeat code in everywhere.And easily change entire loader views in one place

```
Class Helper {
    static func getLoaderViews()->(UIView,NVActivityIndicatorView){
        let activityIndicatorView = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 60, height:60), type: .ballTrianglePath, color: .black)
        let blurView = UIView()
        // create your components,customise and return
        return (blurView,activityIndicatorView)
    }
}
```

now create a **UIViewController** Extension to start or stop loader

```
extension UIViewController {

    func addLoaderToView(view:UIView,blurView:UIView ,activityIndicatorView:NVActivityIndicatorView) {

                blurView.isHidden = false
                blurView.frame = view.frame
                blurView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

                view.addSubview(blurView)
                activityIndicatorView.center = blurView.center
                view.addSubview(activityIndicatorView)
                activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
    }

    func removeLoader(activityIndicatorView:NVActivityIndicatorView,blurView:UIView)  {
        activityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()
        blurView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Now you can easily add or remove loader in any UIViewController

```
    let (blurView,activityIndicatorView) = Helper.getLoaderViews() //In your class scope

//where you want to start
    addLoaderToView(view:self.view,blurView:blurView ,activityIndicatorView:activityIndicatorView)
//where you want to stop
    removeLoader(activityIndicatorView:activityIndicatorView,blurView:blurView)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can create UIView extension

```
extension UIView {
  func showActivity() {
    let activityIndicatorView = NVActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 80, y: 80, width: 60, height:60), type: .ballTrianglePath, color: .black)
    let blurView = UIView()
          DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.blurView.isHidden = false
                self.blurView.frame = self.frame
                self.blurView.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray.withAlphaComponent(0.5)

                self.addSubview(self.blurView)
                self.activityIndicatorView.center = self.blurView.center
                self.addSubview(self.activityIndicatorView)

               self.activityIndicatorView.startAnimating()
            }
     }

}
```